# Why Buttons do not stretch to fill Grid cells?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am about to create a Grid Matrix in a ***UWP application*** and came across this behavior where the Button control does not stretch to fill the available space; in contrast, the TextBox control does. How to force the Button control to behave like a TextBox?

```
     <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5" />
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <TextBox   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="One"   />
        <TextBox  Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="1" Text="Two"   />

        <Button   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Three"   />
        <Button  Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1" Content="Four"   />
    </Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: I see the two buttons stretching! I see a grid of 8 cells where the first two are filled with textboxes and the 2nd and 3rd one is filled with two buttons. There are other 4 empty cells: https://ibb.co/nLJWfk

Comment: Thank you for checking! That is probably because I forgot to mention that I working on a Windows Universal app (UWP). Still very strange why they act differently.

Comment: If you are experienced with WPF, this is a strange change to the default behaviour.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just add those two properties to your buttons:

**HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"**

**VerticalAlignment="Stretch"**

Final buttons definitons:

```
<Button
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    Content="Three" />
<Button
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="1"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    Content="Four" />
```

> Also, the reason those properties need to be overwritten is because in the default Style Template for Button they are set via Setter as Left/Center respectively by default.

Comment: Works perfectly! However, it is still very puzzling of why buttons are not stretched by default even though the default alignment values are set to stretch. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_HorizontalAlignment)

Comment: It would be cleaner to add those property changes for `Stretch` to that parent `Style` template for `Button` he already has in the parent resources as Setters instead of repeating the properties on each instance. Also, the reason those properties need overwritten are because in the default Style Template for `Button` they are set via Setter as Left/Center respectively by default.